# 'elevation' not showing shadow in a ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a strange bug where the 'elevation' attribute is not being shown in my fragments inside a viewpager.

I tried setting the attribute inside the `onCreateView` method of my fragment (**I also set it in the xml-file at the correct position**):

```
containerView.setElevation(Converter.dpToPx(getContext(), 6));
```

The problem is that the elevation is only being shown as soon as the fragment is selected as the current item and fully shown.

A visualization of my error (imgur gif(encoded to mp4)): https://i.imgur.com/DHLx3UM.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself:

The problem was that **I set a custom background drawable by code**:

```
ViewCompat.setBackground(containerView, backgroundDrawable);
```

This `GradientDrawable` was created by code and not in a `drawable-xml` file, which meant that it was not used by the `OutlineProvider`.

My solution was to use an existing `Rectangle Drawable` from an `xml` file, `mutate()` it and set custom colors, corners and everything else to this.